# Modern gumwall light touring tires?

Tags: road-bike, tire, product-rec, vintage, touring-bikes

Are there any modern road/light touring tires which look like the gumwall tires of yesteryear?

In particular, I'm looking for all-weather road tires with serious puncture resistance, i.e. a more-or-less-direct competitor to [Schwalbe's Marathon line](http://www.schwalbe.com/en/tour-reader/marathon.html).

Comment: They were "gumwalls", and the problem with them was that that light-colored rubber rotted in months.  The black coloring ("carbon black") in tires helps them resist UV damage and also improves wear.  If you insist on having a color other than black, try very hard to get tires with silicone rubber, not regular (un-blackened) gum rubber.

Comment: Your info on "why" these tires don't exist much anymore could theoretically answer this [product recommendation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-rec) question while [gaurwraith's answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/39097/8685) provided the required terminology... assuming that the other doesn't get closed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you edited out the picture. I know what a gumwall tire is, but there are probably many younger readers here who have no idea what one is. I think the image makes a good addition to your question.

Comment: @FreeMan: I edited out the picture in order to make the distinction between two nevertheless-related questions more apparent, but the Gods of StackExchange were still not pleased.

Comment: While the other question was closed by votes from our highest rep user and a very experienced moderator, any 5 users with 3000 rep can vote to reopen it. It is sometimes the case that we close questions as duplicates when the questions are different in some way, but the answer is the same. It's about funneling people who are looking for information to the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are called gumwalls. With this keyword you can easily search for them. Brands I see mounted on my friend's bikes are the likes of bontrager, panaracer, schwalbe, but Id say that most tyre manufacturers have a gumwall offer.

Comment: Thanks; I created [a new question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/39100/8685) so you can answer it specifically.

Comment: If I remember correctly, product recomendation is not welcomed, but gumwalls are getting trendy and almost  all brands are offering either a specific road bike gumwall tyre or making already existing models available in gumwall fashion. Thus said, 2 of my friends seen quite happy with bontrager r4, and they are packing serious mileage on the same pair. They are expensive I think.

Comment: Well, someone ironically downvoted my other question despite that this one is the one asking for a recommendation (of course I can't tell who it was), so it looks like someone is unhappy about my decision to split up this question; Answer that one and I'll accept both of them for you

Answer (score 2):

Panaracer Pasela PT are an excellent road/light touring tan sidewall tire, but they're lighter than the Marathon, which is more of a heavy duty loaded touring/urban tire. There's also the Rivendell Ruffy Tuffy, which are decent but I like the Pasela PT more.

The Black/Tan version of the Michelin World Tour is in the same genre as the Marathon but not as nice, and I think it's only been made in 27 and 590. I'm not sure it's made at all anymore.

There are a couple sizes of the Halo Twin Rail in black/tan. I don't really have an opinion about these but the puncture protected ones are kind of in the hybrid/touring genre like the Marathon.