# What are "two-tone" tubular tires called?

Tags: road-bike, tire, vintage, terminology

What are those old "two-tone" [tubular tires](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tires.html#tubular) actually called?-- You know, the ones with the "natural-rubber" color on the sidewalls?

[image: Bottecchia with "two-tone" tires]

Comment: I created this question exactly so that the two questions can be answered separately; Please think before closing.

Comment: But they don't have separate answers.  Please think before cluttering the board with duplicate questions.

Comment: One is asking for a product recommendation and the other one is asking to clarify terminology -- hence related but not the same.

Comment: Read the help text -- we don't do product recommendations.  And you could have simply modified the original question.

Comment: Why is there the tag ["product-rec"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-rec), then?

Comment: @errantlinguist - it depends on how you are asking. If you are asking what brand is "better" - it will be rejected.   Asking about features in a product category will likely be fine

Comment: @Rider_X: Yes, I looked at the differences between the closed `product_rec` questions and those which remained open and thus thought that [my other question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/39095/8685) would be appropriate-- which it seems it is. However, ironically, attempting to extract the secondary question on terminology (which is apparently [a less-contentious tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/terminology)) attracted the ire of many. Surprisingly, attempting to ask multiple "questions" in one Question on e.g. SO leads instantly to closure as "too broad"...

Comment: Are you sure they're tubular tyres?   I know I had normal clinchers in the late 80s that looked the same.   No glue needed, therefore definitely not tubulars.